# Subgraph enumeration

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm

What is an efficient algorithm for the enumeration of all subgraphs of a parent graph.  In my particular case, the parent graph is a molecular graph, and so it will be connected and typically contain fewer than 100 vertices.

Edit:  I am only interested in the connected subgraphs.

Comment: Do you want all subgraphs or all connected subgraphs?

Comment: No matter how efficient you are it is going to take a looong time to enumerate through 2^100 subsets of vertices, and that is before you get into the fact that edges can be there or not.  Can you switch to a problem that is likely to finish before the Sun explodes?

Comment: @btilly: You're right, assuming it's a vertex-labelled graph which is usually the case in applications.  If the vertices aren't labelled (i.e. they aren't distinguishable) then e.g. the complete graph on n vertices has only n subgraphs (including itself).

Comment: I am only interested in the complete subgraphs.  I've edited the question.

Comment: Sorry, that was a brainfart.  I meant connected, not complete.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This question has a better answer in the accepted answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15658245/efficiently-find-all-connected-subgraphs).  It avoids the computationally complex step marked "you fill in above function" in @ninjagecko's answer.  It can deal efficiently with compounds where there are several rings.

See the linked question for the full details, but here's the summary.  (N(v) denotes the set of neighbors of vertex v.  In the "choose a vertex" step, you can choose any arbitrary vertex.)

```
GenerateConnectedSubgraphs(verticesNotYetConsidered, subsetSoFar, neighbors):
    if subsetSoFar is empty:
        let candidates = verticesNotYetConsidered
    else
        let candidates = verticesNotYetConsidered intersect neighbors
    if candidates is empty:
        yield subsetSoFar
    else:
        choose a vertex v from candidates
        GenerateConnectedSubgraphs(verticesNotYetConsidered - {v},
                                   subsetSoFar,
                                   neighbors)
        GenerateConnectedSubgraphs(verticesNotYetConsidered - {v},
                                   subsetSoFar union {v},
                                   neighbors union N(v))
```

Answer (score 4):

> What is an efficient algorithm for the enumeration of all subgraphs of a parent graph. In my particular case, the parent graph is a molecular graph, and so it will be connected and typically contain fewer than 100 vertices.

**Comparison with mathematical subgraphs:**

You could give each element a number from 0 to N, then enumerate each subgraph as any binary number of length N. You wouldn't need to scan the graph at all.

If what you really want is subgraphs with a certain property (**fully connected**, etc.) that is different, and you'd need to update your question. As a commentor noted, 2^100 is very large, so you definitely don't want to (like above) enumerate the mathematically-correct-but-physically-boring disconnected subgraphs. It would literally take you, assuming a billion enumerations per second, at least 40 trillion years to enumerate them all.

**Connected-subgraph-generator:**

If you want some kind of enumeration that retains the DAG property of subgraphs under some metric, e.g. (1,2,3)->(2,3)->(2), (1,2,3)->(1,2)->(2), you'd just want an algorithm that could generate all CONNECTED subgraphs as an iterator (yielding each element). This can be accomplished by recursively removing a single element at a time (optionally from the "boundary"), checking if the remaining set of elements is in a cache (else adding it), yielding it, and recursing. This works fine if your molecule is very chain-like with very few cycles. For example if your element was a 5-pointed star of N elements, it would only have about (100/5)^5 = 3.2million results (less than a second). But if you start adding in more than a single ring, e.g. aromatic compounds and others, you might be in for a rough ride.

e.g. in python

```
class Graph(object):
    def __init__(self, vertices):
        self.vertices = frozenset(vertices)
        # add edge logic here and to methods, etc. etc.

    def subgraphs(self):
        cache = set()
        def helper(graph):
            yield graph
            for element in graph:
                if {{REMOVING ELEMENT WOULD DISCONNECT GRAPH}}:
                    # you fill in above function; easy if
                    # there is 0 or 1 ring in molecule
                    # (keep track if molecule has ring, e.g.
                    #  self.numRings, maybe even more data)
                    # if you know there are 0 rings the operation
                    #  takes O(1) time
                    continue
                subgraph = Graph(graph.vertices-{element})
                if not subgraph in cache:
                    cache.add(subgraph)
                    for s in helper(subgraph):
                        yield s
        for graph in helper(self):
            yield graph

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.vertices == other.vertices
    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(self.vertices)
    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self.vertices)
    def __repr__(self):
        return 'Graph(%s)' % repr(set(self.vertices))
```

Demonstration:

```
G = Graph({1,2,3,4,5})

for subgraph in G.subgraphs():
    print(subgraph)
```

Result:

```
Graph({1, 2, 3, 4, 5})                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
Graph({2, 3, 4, 5})
Graph({3, 4, 5})
Graph({4, 5})
Graph({5})
Graph(set())
Graph({4})
Graph({3, 5})
Graph({3})
Graph({3, 4})
Graph({2, 4, 5})
Graph({2, 5})
Graph({2})
Graph({2, 4})
Graph({2, 3, 5})
Graph({2, 3})
Graph({2, 3, 4})
Graph({1, 3, 4, 5})
Graph({1, 4, 5})
Graph({1, 5})
Graph({1})
Graph({1, 4})
Graph({1, 3, 5})
Graph({1, 3})
Graph({1, 3, 4})
Graph({1, 2, 4, 5})
Graph({1, 2, 5})
Graph({1, 2})
Graph({1, 2, 4})
Graph({1, 2, 3, 5})
Graph({1, 2, 3})
Graph({1, 2, 3, 4})
```

Comment: Unfortunately, more often than not there will be one or several rings in the compounds.  But in the case where the maximum ring count is zero, your algorithm should be fine.

Comment: I think {the ring diameter, or some minimum diameter of something, or the way rings may join to form more complicated structures (e.g. in crystals)} may be more important than the number of rings, with respect to the rough number of subgraphs. This is a separate issue than being able to optimize generating contiguous subgraphs in the above note in the code. Unrelatedly, due to the spatial structure, there may be nice ways to subdivide the problem based on an embedding in 3-space. Just hunches though.

Answer (score 0):

There is this algorithm called gspan [1] that has been used to count frequent subgraphs it can also be used to enumerate all subgraphs. You can find an implementation of it here [2].

The idea is the following: Graphs are represented by so called DFS codes. A DFS code corresponds to a depth first search on a graph G and has an entry of the form
(i, j, l(v_i), l(v_i, v_j), l(v_j)), for each edge (v_i, v_j) of the graph, where the vertex subscripts correspond to the order in which the vertices are discovered by the DFS. It is possible to define a total order on the set of all DFS codes (as is done in [1]) and as a consequence to obtain a canonical graph label for a given graph by computing the minimum over all DFS codes representing this graph. Meaning that if two graphs have the same minimum DFS code they are isomorphic. Now, starting from all possible DFS codes of length 1 (one per edge), all subgraphs of a graph can be enumerated by subsequently adding one edge at a time to the codes which gives rise to an enumeration tree where each node corresponds to a graph. If the enumeration is done carefully (i.e., compatible with the order on the DFS codes) minimal DFS codes are encountered first. Therefore, whenever a DFS code is encountered that is not minimal its corresponding subtree can be pruned. Please consult [1] for further details.

[1] [https://sites.cs.ucsb.edu/~xyan/papers/gSpan.pdf](https://sites.cs.ucsb.edu/%7Exyan/papers/gSpan.pdf)
[2] http://www.nowozin.net/sebastian/gboost/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30287454)