# Full set of subgraphs in Haskell

Tags: haskell, graph

I'm faced with a problem of generating a full set of subgraphs of any graph with limited length. Graphs are represented as lists of ordered pairs, for example:

> let g = [(1,2),(1,7),(1,3),(2,9),(2,4),(3,5),(4,6),(5,6),
>   (7,8),(8,10),(8,9),(10,12),(10,11),(11,13),(12,14),(13,15),(14,15)]

One way is getting all subsequences wherein pairs are bounded, but standard function **subsequences** generates **2^n** variants, at that more of these variants are not bounded, so that represent disconnected subgraphs.

Comment: Doesn't this problem take [O(2^n) time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15658245/efficiently-find-all-connected-subgraphs) to begin with?

Comment: "full set of subgraphs of any graph with limited length", better than O(2^n), enumerate all (breadth-first search) pruning by length.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the way, 
let we have a graph

```
let g = [(1,2),(1,7),(1,3),(2,9),(2,4),(3,5),(4,6),(5,6), (7,8),(8,10),(8,9),(10,12),(10,11),(11,13),(12,14),(13,15),(14,15)]
```

We can get all subgraps by this code:

```
subgraphs g = nub $ subgraphs' g

subgraphs' [] = [[]]
subgraphs' (x:xz) = subgraphs xz ++ map (contact x) (subgraphs xz) 

contact (i,j) [] = [(i,j)]
contact (i,j) set = if ([i] ++ [j]) `intersect` ((\(f,g) -> f ++ g) $ unzip set) /= [] then ([(i,j)] ++ set) else set
```

Test it:

```
*Main> length $ subgraphs g
164
```