# Find all possible combination of nodes in a graph

Tags: java, algorithm, graph

I encountered this problem a while ago and it still haunts me today. Hoping to get some answers.

If you have the below class,

```
class Node {
 String unqId;
 Node[] neighbors;
 Boolean isBlack;
}
```

And a collection of these nodes as illustrated below. How would you write an algorithm that traverses the nodes and outputs all possible combinations of the connected black nodes.

So the answer for this example would be,

```
[a], [b], [d], [f], [h], [i],
[a, b], [a, d], [f, i], [h, i],
[d, a, b], [h, i, f]
```

[image]

I kept it simple for now, but in theory you could probably have nodes which have more than 4 neighbors...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use BFS or DFS to find the connected black components (disregarding edges that lead to white nodes). Then, for each of of these components, find the connected induced subgraphs. For a component of size r this can be done in O(2^r), so in the worst case where all nodes are black this is O(2^n). The details of this step are explained in the accepted answer behind this link.

[Efficiently find all connected induced subgraphs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15658245/efficiently-find-all-connected-induced-subgraphs)

Answer (score 1):

I have attached a brute force solution (`O(m*n^2*2^n)`) where the input is an adjacency list to represent the graph and the output is a collection of arrays of strings to represent the connected nodes.
n is the number of nodes and m is the number of connected nodes.

A quick explanation is that the adjacency list is traversed (`O(n)`) and each black node is added as a one element array to the output. Then all of this black node's neighbors are traversed (`O(m)`) and if they are black they are added to the output as a pair.
It is constant time to check if a node is black.

Finally, inside a while loop check if a new array was added to the output, iterate over the output collection, and check each node in every array to see if it has a black neighbor that would form an array not already present in the output. If yes, add this to the output collection. If a new array was added to the output during this iteration of the while loop, it loops again, otherwise it returns the output collection.
This is `O(m*n^2*2^n)` time because there could be `2^n` arrays in the output, each with `n` elements and each element could have up to `m` neighbors. The while loops iterates at most `n` times.

Edit: @Primusa pointed out the correct possible number of elements in the output collection.

Pseudo Code Brute Force Implementation:

```
output findBlackCombos(AdjacencyList adjList) {

    // n is the number of nodes and m is number of neighbors
    // Output is a collection of arrays of the connected black nodes

    Collection<Array<String>> output;

    // O(m+n) because this is the cost to search through adjacency list
    foreach (node in adjList) {
        if (node.isBlack)
            output.add(new {node.unqID});
        foreach (neighbor in adjList[node.unqID]) {
            if (node.isBlack)
                output.add(new {node.unqID, neighbor.unqId});
        }
    }

    Boolean elementsBeingAdded = true;

    // O(m*n^2*2^n)
    while(elementsBeingAdded) {

        elementsBeingAdded = false;

        foreach(array in output) {
            foreach (node in array) {
                foreach (neighbor in adjList[node.unqID]) {
                    if (!output.Contains({array, neighbor.unqID})) {
                        output.add(new {array, neighbor.unqID});
                        elementsBeingAdded = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return output;

}
```

Comment: I don't think `O(m*n^4)` is possible. Let's say your input is a fully connected graph of N black nodes. Then your output will be the power set of your nodes, which will have `2^N` members.

Comment: Good catch @Primusa, I missed that and will update the post.

Comment: Yup, looks like this will work. I was heading down a similar path but was hoping for a more elegant solution, if one even exists. Will accept shortly if nothing better shows up.