# Efficient Algorithm for subgraph enumeration

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm

I have searched related issues about subgraph enumeration. However, they didn't meet my requirement(*). (If I misunderstood something, please tell me.)

Is there an efficient algorithm or tools for the enumeration of all "connected, and unlabelled" subgraphs of a undirected parent graph.

In my case, the parent graph is an Internet topology so the amount of nodes could be large. And I would like to enumerate all of the connected unlabelled patterns (i.e. subgraphs) of the parent graph.

(*) I have searched [Efficiently find all connected subgraphs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15658245/efficiently-find-all-connected-subgraphs) and [Subgraph enumeration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5984531/subgraph-enumeration) but both of them were targeting on vertex-labelled induced and complete subgraphs respectively. But all I want is just the connected unlabelled subgraphs.

Comment: If the parent graph is vertex-labelled (and all computer representations that I'm aware of are implicitly vertex-labelled), and you want to generate only distinct unlabelled subgraphs, then you need to solve the NP-complete subgraph isomorphism problem many times.  (It's easy to see this if you start with a parent graph that contains two copies of some graph: For any subgraph of the first copy, how can you avoid generating that subgraph a second time when you consider subgraphs of the second copy?)

Comment: @j_random_hacker - The "unlabelled subgraph" requirement in this question is due to my targeting graphs are subnets of Internet topology (i.e. graph of the network). Comparing with other question which are targeting on chemical structure[Note], my question is probably a "unlabelled" subgraphs enumeration problem because any nodes on the Internet are considered to be the same and I am only interested in their pattern.

[Note] Subgraph enumeration [link](http://dalkescientific.com/writings/diary/archive/2011/01/10/subgraph_enumeration.html)

Comment: @j_random_hacker - As you just mentioned, I am aware of there might not exist an efficient algorithm since the repeatedly subgraph isomorphism testing can not be avoided. However, I still wondering if there were any idea that can solve this problem. It would be greatly appreciated for any comment.

Answer (score 1):

A topic name that might be helpful is "frequent subgraph mining", which is what it seems to be one name for this. There are various tools and algorithms in this area, although they may not do exactly what you want, of course.

As other point out in the answers to the two questions in your links, the number of subgraphs of large graphs can be very large. Assuming you actually want to *list* them, not just count them then it might take a long time.

**Edit** : OP has pointed out that the input here is ONE large graph, not a set of smaller ones, which will not work with standard graph mining

I still think the general approach can work here. The input set of graphs for mining is some subset of the subgraphs of your data graph. But that subgraph-set is what you want in the first place!

So lets say you pick a size of subgraph that you want (let's say 6 vertices) then you randomly pick starting vertices in your parent (the internet topology) and 'grow' these seeds, weeding out at each growth step those that don't match. Then repeat for different sizes of subgraph.

Of course, this is a probabilistic algorithm, but it could give you some idea.

Comment: I also have searched the topic before. In my opinion, that issue deals with a graph set with many graphs. And the frequent subgraph mining  algorithm can list out the frequent appearance graphs with a minimum support of the whole graph data set. If I use "frequent subgraph mining" tool[Note] for this problem on purpose (The data set only have ONE graph which is the parent graph and minimum support = 1), I can only got the program in abnormal end (I think that might caused by memory overflow.).

[Note] gSpan [link](http://www.cs.ucsb.edu/~xyan/software/gSpan.htm)

Comment: @TaylorFang Hmm, I see your point. Still it would be surprising to me if there had been NO applications of graph mining to network topologies - or to single large graph inputs in general. For example, there is active research in pattern discovery in chemical reaction networks (such as metabolic networks).

Comment: I really appreciate your help. Let me try to realize your idea in my words. In each iteration, randomly pick seeds and grow by adding edges which share the same endpoint (i.e. the seeds) and prune those don't match by isomorphism testing at the same time. When the size of seeds reach firstly-picked-size, it will be put in the subgraph-set. By increasing the firstly-picked-size, most of the subgraphs will be found as the result.

Comment: @TaylorFang Yes, sounds right. This 'growth' approach is fairly common, and should be well described elsewhere - except of course in the context of multiple input graphs. There might be problems with visiting all subgraphs (of a certain size) exactly once, and there is the question of what to do if two subgraphs start to overlap (although that may not be a problem for you).